# Basic examples of monoids?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, monoid

What are some (simple/elementary) examples of noncommutative monoids with no additional structure? I'm having a hard time thinking of examples of "pure" monoids that aren't monoids simply because they are groups...

I've read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207807/example-of-a-non-commutative-monoid) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142415/is-there-any-monoid-in-which-the-product-of-two-non-invertible-elements-could-be) and some of [this](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/semigroup.pdf), but would like more examples that presuppose little to no algebra.

Comment: @anon: Yes, I read about free monoids in the second link (and then wikipedia).

Comment: I see my first answer is in one of your links. It doesn't presuppose much algebra though. Strings of letters and concatenation are straightforward and do not require abstract algebra to understand. (And one learns about sets and functions for nearly any branch of mathematics, so I think it'd arguably fall under the category of "little to no algebra.") This example seems satisfactory to me, so why aren't you satisfied by it, and why do you think you can't think of non-group monoids when clearly you can (just quotient free monoids but not enough to make a group)?

Comment: @anon: Sorry, I didn't mean that it is an unsatisfactory example. I was just saying that I had read about free monoids. I know some algebra (and hence why I may be constantly thinking of groups), but I only wanted very basic monoid examples for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free monoids are pretty intuitive at heart: strings of letters under a concatenation operation.

Also, the set of functions $X\to X$ on a set (no stipulation of being bijective). More generally the set of endomorphisms of an arbitrary object of an arbitrary category caries a monoid structure under composition, so in particular functions on a set and linear maps on a vector space (categories in general constitute an abstract algebra background, but sets and vector spaces not as much).

If $G$ is an arbitrary group (which is admittedly an essentially algebraic concept), in your case noncommutative, one can adjoin a zero element (in the literature's lingo, an absorption element) and easily make the set $G\cup\{0\}$ into a monoid that is not a group. (For fun, this process can be continued indefinitely to create bigger and bigger monoids.) This idea is pretty straightforward.

Comment: The first one is just a *free* monoid.

Comment: @FrankScience yes, that's what my sentence says.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mathfrak{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of real square matrices of order $n$ and $\circ$ the operation of [matrix product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29), then $(\mathfrak{M}_n(\mathbb{R}),\circ)$ is a monoid for all $n\ge 2$.

It is not commutative: for $n=2$ it is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\circ\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\ne\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\circ\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

It is not a group, since all matrices with determinant $0$ have no inverse. For example, for $n=2$, the identity element is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and there's no $A\in\mathfrak{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$A\circ\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
([SLM](https://books.google.it/books?id=TS7YPQAACAAJ), pp. 37-38).

---

Let $A$ be a non empty set, $A^A$ denote the set of all functions $f\colon A\to A$ and $\circ$ denote the composition of functions defined, for all $f,g\in A^A$, as
$$(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x)),\ \forall x\in A.$$
Then $(A^A,\circ)$ is a monoid with identity element $Id$, defined
$$Id(x)=x,\ \forall x\in A$$
([SVTL](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZG08PQAACAAJ), pp. 164-165). Again, such monoid is not commutative and is not a group: can you prove it?

Comment: Just a quick question. Is it sufficient to say that there is an identity element $Id$? Doesn't one need to explicitly find what that identity element (or identity function in this case)?

Comment: @Ufomammut yes, of course I'd say, that's why I specified it in both the examples (although I did not demonstrate it) in this answer some 4 years ago... :)

Answer (score 3):

A generic answer is the monoid of all functions from a set $E$ into itself under the composition of functions. This example is generic since **every** monoid is isomorphic to a submonoid of such a monoid. In particular, take any set of functions from $E$ to $E$ and close under composition: you will get a monoid. See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_semigroup). This type of example occurs frequently in automata theory.

You could also consider partial functions or relations on $E$, still under composition. The monoid of $n \times n$ matrices over a ring under the usual multiplication of matrices is also a quite natural example. If you have a monoid $M$, the set $\mathcal{P}(M)$ of all subsets of $M$ is also a monoid under multiplication defined by
$XY = \{ xy \mid x \in X, y \in Y \}$ (where $X, Y \in \mathcal{P}(M)$).